# document.getElementById() returns NULL getting value from DropDownList

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this code:

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOpRep" runat="server" Width="70px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
```

Now I want to show a confirmation msg with the selected value in the ddlOpRep:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRelease" runat="server" Text="Release" Width="130px" 
         OnClientClick="return confirmRelease();" onclick="btnRelease_Click" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmRelease() {
        var OpRep = document.getElementById("ddlOpRep");           

        return confirm('Are you sure you want to release this configuration: OpRep: ' + OpRep + ' ?');
    }
</script>
```

But I'm getting `null` at `var OpRep = document.getElementById("ddlOpRep");`

So not even the possibility to get `var OpRep = document.getElementById("ddlOpRep").value;`

Comment: It's ASP.  You have to ask it for the actual id it generates.

Comment: Have a look at the rendered html.  I'm guessing you'll be surprised when you see what your `id` value really is.

Comment: If you're using .Net 4 or above you can set the `ClientIDMode` to `static` on the control. Then the ID will be what you specify but you have to ensure the ID is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ASP.NET, get the `ClientID`

```
var OpRep = document.getElementById("<%= ddlOpRep.ClientID %>");
```

Answer (score 2):

In javascript function you need to pass the actual generated Id of the dropdown. So Either you can get the client id like this

```
document.getElementById("<%= ddlOpRep.ClientID %>");
```

or You can set the `ClientIdMode="Static"` in dropdown property.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOpRep" runat="server" Width="70px" ClientIdMode="Static">
```

Comment: Thanks for clarify me that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ClientID to get the element because you are using ASP.NET.
It should look something like this:

```
var newObject = document.getElementById("<%= ASPObject.ClientID %>");
```

where ASPObject is the ASP.NET object you are looking for.